# AgGrid version 22.1 and Angular 10

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I just upgraded to Angular 10 and now the enterprise version of AgGrid is no longer working. I don't get the watermark or the console warning about not having a license, I just don't get the enterprise features.

Package JSON

```
"ag-grid-angular": "22.1.0",
"ag-grid-community": "22.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "22.1.0",
```

Module.ts

```
import { LicenseManager } from 'ag-grid-enterprise';
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey(myKey)
```

If I upgrade the agGrid packages to version 23 everything works, but I am trying to avoid the major styling changes of v23 right now. Based on the compatibility chart it says v23 is recommended, but doesnt say its a breaking change. Anyone have luck getting version 22.1 to work with Angular 10?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nate If you are an enterprise user you can contact ZenDesk to get more detail on this since developers at AG-Grid know this better. Since they have recommended v23 over former ones and your issue is to avoid major styling changes. For your specific case i guess they(support) are the best option to get solution.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, will do!

Answer (score 0):

Quick update on this. Turns out that this issue is actually just a clipboard issue with AgGrid Version 22, all other enterprise features work.

This issue happens when you import the entire package of AgGrid and are not importing modules.

To fix this issue upgrade to version 23+ or if you need to stay on version 22 for longer you can add the following code to fix it.

Package.josn:

`"@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard": "22.1.0"`,

In the component file:

`import { ModuleRegistry } from 'ag-grid-community';`

`import { ClipboardModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard';`

`ModuleRegistry.register(ClipboardModule as any);`